# Where does DLL that get called from JNI get its memory for allocation such as Malloc

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, libpng

In my case, `savePngImage()` in java side is a static function that calls native `nativeSavePngImage()` in JNI that uses `libpng` library.

FYI, the function is accessed by multiple threads in the program and the application is saving more than hundred thousands of images progressively and at one point in which the image count reaches hundred thousand, `png_create_write_struct()` return NULL as a result of failure to allocate memory. The memory settings in `java` is `-Xms24G -Xmx24G -Xmn20G` and at the time when the error happens, physical memory usage is only at 30% of 128GB.

BTW, memory leaks in native code does not seems like a problem as the memory shown in task manager is not actually showing an increasing trend although i might be very wrong about it.

```
// create the png structures
png_structp pWriteStruct = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING,
                                                   (png_voidp)NULL,
                                                   pngErrorFunction,
                                                   pngErrorFunction);

if (pWriteStruct == NULL)
{
  fclose(pFile);
  sptAssert(false); //getting assertion here
  return;
}
```

Thus, my question is how can we know whether the native memory in JNI is hitting its limit thus `png_create_write_struct()` is unable to allocate the memory.

I am really sorry if the current above information wont help in determining the causes and would update the post if more debugging information can be gotten from your guys suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc()` returns memory out of the C heap, and whether that's the entire process's C heap or the DLL's own heap depends on whether the DLL and the process are sharing the same dynamic C library or not.

JNI and the Java heap have exactly nothing to do with it in either case.

The rest of your question is back to front. You know that `png_create_write_struct()` has run out of memory *when it returns NULL.*

Comment: Can I know how do we check whether the memory allocation is in dll own heap or the entire process c heap?

Comment: Not unless you know how the DLL was built. But you shouldn't need to know.